# How do I disable Google Chrome's pop-ups?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

I'm using Google Chrome on Windows 7.
Whenever I'm writing a post and leave it incomplete, or if I'm using a web chat site, like omegle, when I attempt to close the tab, Chrome gives me a pop-up, asking me to confirm if I *actually* do want to leave the page.

Is there any way to disable these pop-ups?

I've checked all the settings but I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are talking about is not specific to Chrome. It occurs in whatever browser you use and is part of the website you are viewing. [image]

The pop-up is usually used to prevent a user from existing a page while unsaved content is still running, such as a form, post or playlist etc. The box is part of the website you are visiting rather than a part of the browser.

As such there is not a lot you can do about it short of a custom script to block site behavior.